# Overriding class methods in ObjectiveC

Tags: ios, objective-c

Considering the following case:

```
@interface Superclass : NSObject
...
@end

@interface Superclass

+ (void)methodToOverride
{
    NSLog(@"This method should be overridden by subclass!");
}

+ (void)callMethodToOverride
{
    [self methodToOverride];
}

@end

@interface SubClass : SuperClass
...
@end

@implementation SubClass

+ (void)methodToOverride
{
    NSLog(@"I'm overriding this method!");
}

@end
```

Now, when calling

```
[Subclass callMethodToOverride];
```

I get `"This method should be overridden by subclass!"`. Is it possible to get `I'm overriding this method!` instead or is this not possible with ObjC's static methods?

Cheers!

Comment: There is no such thing as a static method in Objective-C. The methods in your question are class methods (as opposed to instance methods).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use this paradigm from time to time and it works for me. In my implementations, I'm referencing `[self class]` instead of `self`. Maybe that's the key you're missing.

```
+ (void)callMethodToOverride
{
  [[self class] methodToOverride];
  NSLog(@"This is the class that I just used: %@", NSStringFromClass(self));
}
```

Sounds like it could just be a typo where you're not using the class you think you are.

Comment: In a class method, `self` is the class so `self` and `[self class]` are equivalent.

Comment: I don't disagree; it shouldn't make a difference. I was sharing what I know to be true about the code that I work with.

Comment: Thanks, it worked! I was somewhat calling [Superclass methodToOverride] instead of [self methodToOverride]! Problem solved :)